# Local Kubernetes on CentOS

Tags: centos, kubernetes, centos6

I am trying to install Kubernetes locally on my CentOS. I am following this blog http://containertutorials.com/get_started_kubernetes/index.html, with appropriate changes to match CentOS and latest Kubernetes version.

./kube-up.sh script runs and exists with no errors and I don't see the server started on port 8080. Is there a way to know what was the error and if there is any other procedure to follow on CentOS 6.3

Comment: What release did you wget? There was a previous issue with iptables on centos 6 https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/37594

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to install the kubernetes cluster is using `kubeadm`. The initial post which details the steps of setup is [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/). And the detailed documentation for the kubeadm can be found [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kubeadm/). With this you will get the latest released kubernetes.

---

If you really want to use the script to bring up the cluster, I did following:

Install the required packages

```
yum install -y git docker etcd
```

Start `docker` process

```
systemctl enable --now docker
```

Install `golang`
Latest go version because default centos golang is old and for kubernetes to compile we need at least `go1.7`

```
curl -O https://storage.googleapis.com/golang/go1.8.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz
tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.8.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

Setup `GOPATH`

```
export GOPATH=~/go
export GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$GOBIN
```

Download k8s source and other golang dependencies

**Note**: this might take sometime depending on your internet speed

```
go get -d k8s.io/kubernetes
go get -u github.com/cloudflare/cfssl/cmd/...
```

Start cluster

```
cd $GOPATH/src/k8s.io/kubernetes
./hack/local-up-cluster.sh
```

In new terminal

```
alias kubectl=$GOPATH/src/k8s.io/kubernetes/cluster/kubectl.sh
kubectl get nodes
```